# Acronym within an acronym, academic writing

Tags: writing, acronyms, medical

I'm preparing a manuscript for publication in a medical journal about Inflammatory Bowel Disease (IBD). I understand that I have to define the acronym IBD once, when first used in the text (technically twice, both in the abstract and main text). 'Inflammatory Bowel Disease' is also part of the study name, which has its own acronym. If I have already introduced 'IBD', can I use this acronym when defining the acronym for the study name?

Example:

> "Inflammatory Bowel Disease (IBD) is a chronic disease [...] The Treatment of Inflammatory Bowel Disease in Daily Practice (TIBDDP) study..."

Or:

> "Inflammatory Bowel Disease (IBD) is a chronic disease [...] The Treatment of IBD in Daily Practice (TIBDDP) study..."

Just as a note: IBD is an acronym that is commonly used and well-known among my target audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Inflammatory Bowel Disease" is a condition and most publications require that you write the term in full the first time it is mentioned in the text, followed by its acronym in parentheses. From then on all you do is use only the acronym.  Then again, your study about IFD has a very long title and includes IBD in it. It also needs an acronym for the text but I wouldn't use TIBDDP.  I would coin a shorter one instead. (e.g. The Treatment of Inflammatory Bowel Disease in Daily Practice study (TIDS) sounds better.

Comment: @ no problem. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't coin the acronym TIBDDP and I am not in the position to change it (I understand your concern however). Thanks for the answer!